# render().el returns nothing in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone. I'm trying to implement tabs through the backbone. There are three views TabView, TabListView and appView. My idea is to load the TabListView using the TabView in the appView.

template and rest of the HTML content already handled in another page. I have managed to make work this page. But it is not returning data with the following statement.

this.$el.html(new TabListView().render().el);

Here is the complete listing of my code.

```
var app = app || {};


var Tab = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:""
    }
});

var TabList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Tab
});

var TabView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"div",
    className:"headerTab", /* Dynamically creates */
    template:$("#tabTemplate").html(),

    render:function () {
        var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

        this.$el.html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var tabs = [
    {id:"one", name:"Tab1"},
    {id:"two", name:"Tab2"},
    {id:"three", name:"Tab3"}       
];

var TabListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#headerTabMenu'),
    initialize:function(){
        this.collection = new TabList(tabs);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){        
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (tab) {            
            $(this.el).append(new TabView({model:tab}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#contentContainer',   
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('Application started!');
        //this.$el.html('Test content');

        // HERE IS THE ISSUE WHY el IS NOT RETUNS THE HTML?  
        this.$el.html(new TabListView().render().el);

    }
});
var myApp = new app.AppView();
```

Comment: Where's the code that instantiates an app.AppView?

Comment: This was not the issue. I have added app.AppView initialization in another file (anyway updated that also here)

Comment: Where's the templates you reference when you select them for the templating call?

Comment: HTML is in another page and basic is working only the issue is with the line : this.$el.html(new TabListView().render().el);

Comment: Right, but since that line ultimately involves grabbing the template content, it would be useful to include it.

Comment: Don't use `el: $('#headerTabMenu')`, use `el: '#headerTabMenu'` to avoid timing problems. Don't use `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)`, use `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... })`. Don't use `$(this.el)`, use `this.$el`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have modified the code as you mentioned, but it is not showing anything in the page. 
the tab <div id="contentContainer"></div> is still empty.                           
var tab = new Tab({id:"tab1", name:"Tab One"});        
console.log(new TabView({model:tab}).render().el);  
// This logs the message. So I think, TabView returns data to TabListView, but TabListView is NOT returns data to app.AppView.

Comment: TabView returns data to TabListView, but TabListView is NOT returns data to app.AppView